# SimpleXML Path annotation ignored

Tags: android, xml, xpath, kotlin, simple-framework

I am wondering how the @Path annotation from simplexml works for kotlin on Android  (or better if it works at all).

The given XML will demonstrate the problem

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<start >
    <one>never</one>
    <firstlevel>
        <secondlevel>
            <one>always</one>
            <testelement>1</testelement>
            <testlist>
                <title>1</title>
                <active>false</active>
            </testlist>
            <testlist>
                <title>2</title>
                <active>false</active>
            </testlist>
            <testlist>
                <title>3</title>
                <active>false</active>
                <testobject>
                    <testbyte>127</testbyte>
                </testobject>
            </testlist>
        </secondlevel>
    </firstlevel>
</start>
```

and the objects

```kotlin
@Root(name = "start", strict = false)
data class Baseobj constructor(

    @field:ElementList(name = "testlist", inline = true, required = false)
    @param:ElementList(name = "testlist", inline = true, required = false)
    @Path("firstlevel/secondlevel")
    var testlist: List<testlist>? = listOf(),

    @field:Element(name = "testelement", required = false)
    @param:Element(name = "testelement", required = false)
    @Path("firstlevel/secondlevel")
    var testelement: String? = null,

    @Path("firstlevel/secondlevel")
    @field:Element(name = "one", required = false)
    @param:Element(name = "one", required = false)
    var one: String? = null
)
```

the corresponding classes

```kotlin
@Root(strict = false, name = "testlist")
data class testlist constructor(
    @field:Element(required = false, name = "title")
    @param:Element(required = false, name = "title")
    var title: String? = null,


    @field:Element(required = false, name = "active")
    @param:Element(required = false, name = "active")
    var active: String? = null
)
```

with the Test

```kotlin
@Test
fun should_ParseTestXML() {
    val serializer = Persister()
    val stream = javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/raw/test.xml")
    val base = serializer.read(Baseobj::class.java, stream)

    println("Here we are: ${base.testelement} ${base.one}")
}
```

would print out `"Here we are: null never"` which isn't the expected or – at least – the desired behavior. SimpleXML is included by the retrofit package

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.4.0'
implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.4.0') {
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}
```

In my current project the xml is much more complex and object structure should not include wrapping objects. Despite the existence of converters which I am aware of, I'd like to have a solution based on XPath usages.

Thank you in advance

Michael

Comment: Do the results change if you declare these classes in Java?

Comment: Yes, the Java implementation works flawless.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
    @field:Path("firstlevel/secondlevel")
    @param:Path("firstlevel/secondlevel")
```

This declares the annotation for java based framesworks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
@field:Element(name = "testelement", required = false)
@param:Element(name = "testelement", required = false)
@Path("firstlevel/secondlevel")
var testelement: String? = null,
```

Try this

```
@field:Element(name = "testelement", required = false)
@param:Element(name = "testelement", required = false)
@field:Path("firstlevel/secondlevel")  <=========================
var testelement: String? = null,
```